# Read SOAP response xml using php, is cannot read xml file

Tags: php, xml

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP:Body>
        <air:LowFareSearchRsp TransactionId="6F965E450A076478B86F876C892DCB3B" ResponseTime="42833" DistanceUnits="MI" CurrencyType="LKR" xmlns:air="http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v25_0" xmlns:common_v25_0="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v25_0">
            <common_v25_0:ResponseMessage Code="2027" Type="Warning" ProviderCode="1P">Requested date is out of provider supported date range. Results may have been returned with other dates.</common_v25_0:ResponseMessage>
            <air:FlightDetailsList>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="/f+YonrXRQKE6/ePot1icg==" Origin="CMB" Destination="BKK" DepartureTime="2015-11-14T01:40:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2015-11-14T06:35:00.000+07:00" FlightTime="205" TravelTime="205" Distance="1485" Equipment="320"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="RZaPXzrqT7aBia5Rv5HDSw==" Origin="CMB" Destination="BKK" DepartureTime="2015-11-14T07:20:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2015-11-14T12:15:00.000+07:00" FlightTime="205" TravelTime="205" Distance="1485" Equipment="332"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="jZVn/oAjTOGbbPrq7V0WXQ==" Origin="CMB" Destination="KUL" DepartureTime="2015-11-14T00:40:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2015-11-14T06:55:00.000+08:00" FlightTime="225" TravelTime="225" Distance="1530" Equipment="320" DestinationTerminal="M"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="47Vb5TYpQpGruHS0FlMuEA==" Origin="KUL" Destination="BKK" DepartureTime="2015-11-14T13:05:00.000+08:00" ArrivalTime="2015-11-14T14:10:00.000+07:00" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="495" Distance="759" Equipment="787" OriginTerminal="M"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="S4cPtkw/TiWUazgonAmzrw==" Origin="CMB" Destination="KUL" DepartureTime="2015-11-14T07:30:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2015-11-14T13:45:00.000+08:00" FlightTime="225" TravelTime="225" Distance="1530" Equipment="321" DestinationTerminal="M"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="5hrw3GrAQ929uDyp8ROe7A==" Origin="KUL" Destination="BKK" DepartureTime="2015-11-14T21:00:00.000+08:00" ArrivalTime="2015-11-14T22:05:00.000+07:00" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="560" Distance="759" Equipment="787" OriginTerminal="M"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="9W5gjL57STePdYm7f6DPIA==" Origin="KUL" Destination="BKK" DepartureTime="2015-11-14T15:15:00.000+08:00" ArrivalTime=
```

How can I read this file with php? I tried to read it  SimpleXMLElement but it does not read file and give empty object

Comment: Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ibe\uapi_CURL_Air.php on line 91
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quo in C:\xampp\htdocs\ibe\uapi_CURL_Air.php on line 91
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\ibe\uapi_CURL_Air.php on line 91

Comment: Please, edit your question with additional information, instead of adding them into comments.

Answer (score 0):

How did you try to read the xml? Did you may forgot to register your xpath Namespace?

Here is an example, being $yourSoapResponse the string response of your request:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($yourSoapResponse); 
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$body = $xml->xpath("//soap:Body");
print_r($body);
```

Comment: I followed same method but it gives  
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Undefined namespace prefix in C:\xampp\htdocs\ibe\xmltest.php on line 22

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): xmlXPathEval: 1 object left on the stack in C:\xampp\htdocs\ibe\xmltest.php on line 22

Comment: What if you write the soap in upper case?